# Distribution of random walk changes

Tags: probability, random-walk, time-series

Say that $R_t = R_{t-1}+e_t$, where $e \overset{i.i.d.}\sim N(o, \sigma^2)$. Take now $\Delta R_t = e_t$, which is the differenced series. Say now that
$S_t$ is equal to 1 whenever $
\Delta R_t \geq 0$ and - 1 otherwise. Can we argue that $S_t \overset{i.i.d.} \sim Bernoulli(p) $? Where $p=P(S_t=1)$. To me it seems reasonable given the definition of $\Delta R_t$, but could you provide a rigorous proof or disproof? Moreover, is it correct to include the case $\Delta R_t = 0$ with $\Delta R_t > 0$? It seems correct to me since virtually $P(\Delta R_t = 0) = 0$. Thank you.

Comment: In fact, $p=1/2$...

Comment: It seems also trivial to me, but is it right to argue directly that p=1/2 given the definition of $\Delta R_t$? Is it also true that $ P(\Delta R_t = 0) = 0$? I want to be as rigorous as possible.

Comment: Yes. All these facts follow from the equality $\Delta R_t=e_t$. Btw, formally $S_t=1\{R_t\ge 0\}\sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$.